# SQLite: search keywords' table with separate rows and joining multiple tables

Tags: sqlite, outer-join

I have three SQLite tables, a *products* table, a *keywords_products* table, and a *keywords* table.

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    product_rec_id  INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
    name            VARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE keywords_products (
    keyword_rec_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    product_rec_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE keywords (
    keyword_rec_id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
    keyword        VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL  UNIQUE
);
```

The *keywords_products* table holds the the record id of a product and a record id of a keyword. Each product can be assigned multiple keywords in the *keywords* table.

The *keyword* table looks like this:

```
keyword_rec_id  keyword
--------------  -----------
60              melee
43              scifi
87              water
```

The *keywords_products* table looks like this (one keyword can be assigned to many products):

```
keyword_rec_id  product_rec_id
--------------  --------------
43              1
60              1
43              2
87              3
```

The *products* table looks like this:

```
product_rec_id  name
--------------  --------------
1               Scifi Melee Weapons
2               Scifi Ray Weapon
3               Lake House
```

For a long time I have been using this SQL command, but I just noticed that for an AND operation it will not work, obviously, because all the keywords are in separate rows.

```
SELECT
  products.product_rec_id,
  keywords.keyword
FROM
  products
  LEFT OUTER JOIN keywords_products ON
    products.product_rec_id = keywords_products.product_rec_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN keywords ON
    keywords_products.keyword_rec_id = keywords.keyword_rec_id
WHERE
  (keywords.keyword LIKE '%scifi%' OR
    keywords.keyword LIKE '%melee%')
```

Sometimes I want to be able to retrieve products matching all the keywords entered (AND) or just one of the keywords (OR) (the OR operation is the only one I can do now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT  products.product_rec_id, COUNT(DISTINCT keywords.keyword) AS cnt
FROM  products
LEFT OUTER JOIN keywords_products ON
    products.product_rec_id = keywords_products.product_rec_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN keywords ON
    keywords_products.keyword_rec_id = keywords.keyword_rec_id
WHERE  (keywords.keyword LIKE '%scifi%' OR   keywords.keyword LIKE '%melee%')
GROUP BY products.product_rec_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN keywords.keyword LIKE '%scifi%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0
  AND SUM(CASE WHEN keywords.keyword LIKE '%melee%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

**EDIT:**

To get both at the same time (if in the same row):

```
SELECT  products.product_rec_id,keywords.keyword
FROM  products
LEFT OUTER JOIN keywords_products ON
    products.product_rec_id = keywords_products.product_rec_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN keywords ON
    keywords_products.keyword_rec_id = keywords.keyword_rec_id
WHERE  keywords.keyword LIKE '%scifi%melee%'
   OR keywords.keyword LIKE '%melee%scifi%';
```

Comment: The HAVING is behaving in the same manner as the WHERE, OR works but not AND.

Comment: @nDelphi No it doesn't behave the same way. WHERE works on row-level, HAVING on group of rows

Comment: In the sense that as written in this case they return the same results. Also, this will never work: keywords.keyword LIKE '%scifi%melee%' as the keywords are in separate rows.

I edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: It does work, the culprit was ",keywords.keyword" in the GROUP BY products.product_rec_id,keywords.keyword.

Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: I am having a tough time trying to get a count with the addition of the HAVINGs. Can you, please, point me in the right direction?

Comment: @nDelphi Do you mean `, COUNT(DISTINCT keywords.keyword) AS cnt`?

Comment: I am pulling count(Distinct products.product_rec_id) as TRows to pass to a pagination value. I need to get it to work with the HAVING code added to it. That HAVING part is only used when a search by keyword is done.

Comment: I think I managed it. I have this code without the HAVING. The results in this case should 310 for TRows and 84 (Kwords2) and that is what I am getting. Does this look correct to you?

SELECT Count(DISTINCT products.product_rec_id) AS TRows,
       Count((CASE
                 WHEN keywords.keyword LIKE '%purchased%'
                 THEN 1
             END)  and
       (CASE
                 WHEN keywords.keyword LIKE '%item%'
                 THEN 1
             END)) AS Kwords2
FROM products....